# Understanding the application.ini and the bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-application

I have been trying to figure this out for quite a while, but what is the exact difference between the application.ini and the bootstrap file in a Zend Project?

Both seem to be used to add resources, helpers, etc. But i do not quite understand what the difference is between adding something in the bootstrap or adding it trough the application.ini. What is the benefit of either approach against the other?

Is there anyone who could explain this to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the Zend Framework Bootstrap process and resource loading from application.ini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366930/understanding-the-zend-framework-bootstrap-process-and-resource-loading-from-app)

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002346/how-bootstrap-works-in-general-and-particularly-in-zend-framework/11002906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration set out in `application.ini` drives the built in (and any 3rd party or custom built) [application resource plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html). You are limited by what the resource plugins can do with your config settings.

Any code in your Bootstrap class is meant to offer more fine-grained customisation. Here you can do anything you're able to put into PHP code.